# Add view from table view cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, click, row

I know this question has been asked before but mine is different. My app has an add button and edit button that deletes/adds table views. I want every cell that is created by the user to go to the same view. I've been looking everywhere for the code but I can't find it. BTW the ____ is just a placeholder. The table coding is in the app delegate and I have a second view controller for the view that is loaded when a row is clicked.

**AppDelegate.h**

```
@interface _____AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    CustomCellViewController *customCellViewController;

    IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
    IBOutlet UITableViewCell *customCell;

    NSMutableArray *data;
    IBOutlet UITableView *mainTableView;
    IBOutlet UINavigationItem *navItem;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CustomCellViewController *customCellViewController;

- (IBAction)addRowToTableView;
- (IBAction)editTable;
- (NSString *)dataFilePath;

@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "______AppDelegate.h"

@implementation ______AppDelegate;

@synthesize window;
@synthesize navController=_navController;
@synthesize customCellViewController;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

    NSArray *archivedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[self dataFilePath]];
    if (archivedArray == nil) {

        data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];                 

    } else {
        data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:archivedArray];
    }



    // Override point for customization after application launch
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (IBAction)addRowToTableView {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"New Product" message:@"What is the name of your product?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];

    [alert addTextFieldWithValue:@"" label:@"Name of product..."];

    UITextField *tf = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    tf.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    tf.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeURL;
    tf.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
    tf.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    tf.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;



    [alert show];   

}


-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alert clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (buttonIndex == 1) {

        UITextField *tf = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];


        [data addObject:tf.text];
        [self saveData];
        [mainTableView reloadData];     

    }
}




- (IBAction)editTable {

    UIBarButtonItem *leftItem;

    [mainTableView setEditing:!mainTableView.editing animated:YES];

    if (mainTableView.editing) {

        leftItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(editTable)];

    } else {

        leftItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(editTable)];


    }

    navItem.rightBarButtonItem = leftItem;
    [self saveData];
    [mainTableView reloadData];
}


- (IBAction)endText {

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [data count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifer = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:"Cell"] autorelease];

    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;

}

- (NSString *)dataFilePath {

    NSString *dataFilePath;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    dataFilePath = [[documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"applicationData.plist"] retain];
    return dataFilePath;

}

- (void)saveData {

    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:[data copy]  toFile:[self dataFilePath]];

}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [data removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];


}


- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath
      toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
    NSString *item = [[data objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row] retain];
    [data removeObject:item];
    [data insertObject:item atIndex:toIndexPath.row];
    [item release];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];


}



- (void)dealloc {
    [window release];
    [_navController release];
    [customCellViewController release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: Here's a few pointers: First, I did not understand beyond the button that adds/deletes table views... What app created by the user are you talking about? Second, the point of developing is not "looking everywhere for the code". Third, IMO, replacing part of the name of your class with ___ is quite pretentious, like your app is so awesome we can't even know the slightest detail; just remove that part of the name if it's so confidential... And finally, I hope you are using ARC...

Comment: Every cell* my bad. and I'm looking for the code because i cannot pull it out of my ass, unfortunately. Third, who cares what the class is named, you know what it means right? then you're fine. What's ARC?

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to be harsh, but you have a lot of basics to learn. ARC will make your life much easier and your code better, by eliminating the need to manually manage memory (for the most part). You can enable it when you first start a project. You should.

Why is an App Delegate managing a table view? No, no no. The app delegate is supposed to respond to system-level events, not run your whole application. You need a separate view controller. Find some tutorials around the web and see how a basic app using a table view is structured. There are many. My favorites are on raywenderlich.com